# I need to understand the JOLT functions like #, @, &, () and []

Tags: json, jolt

I'm having another problem, consider this JSON:

```json
{
  "found": true,
  "consultado": "00000000",
  "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 00000000 LTDA",
  "socio": [
    {
      "cpfCnpj": "11111111111",
      "nome": "PESSOA DE CPF 11111111111",
      "descricaoCargo": "Sócio",
      "outrasEmpresasSocio": [
        {
          "cnpj": "11111111",
          "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 11111111 LTDA",
          "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cpfCnpj": "00000000000",
      "nome": "PESSOA DE CPF 00000000000",
      "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador",
      "outrasEmpresasSocio": [
        {
          "cnpj": "11111111",
          "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 11111111 LTDA",
          "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
        },
        {
          "cnpj": "22222222",
          "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 22222222 LTDA",
          "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
        },
        {
          "cnpj": "33333333",
          "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 33333333 LTDA",
          "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I go through it and get each field socio.cpfCnpj, socio.nome, socio.descricaoCargo and each socio.outrasEmpresasSocio.cnpj, socio.outrasEmpresasSocio.nome and socio.outrasEmpresasSocio.descricaoCargo.

The result should be:

```json
[
  {
    "cpfCnpj": "11111111111",
    "nome": "PESSOA DE CPF 11111111111",
    "cnpj": "11111111",
    "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 11111111 LTDA",
    "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
  },
  {
    "cpfCnpj": "00000000000",
    "nome": "PESSOA DE CPF 00000000000",
    "cnpj": "11111111",
    "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 11111111 LTDA",
    "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
  },
  {
    "cpfCnpj": "00000000000",
    "nome": "PESSOA DE CPF 00000000000",
    "cnpj": "22222222",
    "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 22222222 LTDA",
    "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
  },
  {
    "cpfCnpj": "00000000000",
    "nome": "PESSOA DE CPF 00000000000",
    "cnpj": "33333333",
    "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 33333333 LTDA",
    "descricaoCargo": "Sócio-Administrador"
  }
]
```

I still get lost trying to understand the #, @, &, () and [] functions in JOLT.

Could you help me with the problem and explain these functions to me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to loop within the objects of the "outrasEmpresasSocio" arrays while bringing two attributes `cpfCnpj` and `nome` from two levels upper level( by using such as **@2,cpfCnpj** ), and separate the levels by using the indexes of the arrays `"socio"` and `"outrasEmpresasSocio"` for which going 1 and 3 levels up the tree would be needed, and combining them I got the common identifier **&3_&1** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "socio": {
        "*": {
          "outrasEmpresasSocio": {
            "*": {
              "@2,cpfCnpj": "&3_&1.cpfCnpj",
              "@2,nome": "&3_&1.nomeOut",
              "*": "&3_&1.&" // asterisk( "*" ) represents all elements within 
                             // the current respective object
                             // & which stays at the rightmost represents
                             // the leaf node to replicate the value of the current 
                             // attribute, indeed & is identical to &0 where
                             // zero means the current level
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.
I'm going to delve deeper into what you explained to me and try to redo it for the last point:
"participacaoEmpresa"
And try to go through as you demonstrated in "socio" (I managed to replicate it for "Administrador").
With your help I realized where I was failing and found a course to better understand LHS (or left hand side) and RHS (or right hand side).

Comment: How would you do JOLT for this case:

I have this:

{
  "found": true,
  "consultado": "00000000",
  "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 00000000 LTDA",
  "participacaoEmpresa": [
    {
      "cnpj": "44444444",
      "nome": "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 44444444 LTDA",
      "descricaoCargo": "Sócio"
    }
  ]
}

This want to be this:

{
  "CNPJ_PSSA_JUDC" : "44444444",
  "NOME_PSSA_JUDC" : "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 44444444 LTDA",
  "DCRC_CRGO" : "Sócio",
  "DOCT_SCIO" : "00000000",
  "NOME_SCIO" : "EMPRESA DE CNPJ 00000000 LTDA"
}
I'm sorry the JSON is unformatted.

Comment: @MateusCostaLuz You can use ```[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "participacaoEmpresa": {
        "*": {
          "cnpj": "CNPJ_PSSA_JUDC",
          "nome": "NOME_PSSA_JUDC",
          "descricaoCargo": "DCRC_CRGO",
          "@2,consultado": "DOCT_SCIO",
          "@2,nome": "NOME_SCIO"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```  take care.

Comment: Why I need to take care? I've tried here and this is functional. Thanks again.

Comment: @MateusCostaLuz I've told nothing but "take care of yourself" (just a greetng) :)

Comment: I've tryied ur JOLT but when I've anothers elements at "participacaoEmpresa" array this JOLT will return me another lists. How can I do the get each element?
Don't care about my question about to take care, I was just surprised and scared (my English isn't so good). D:

Comment: @MateusCostaLuz depends on that what you have met(need to see it). Renaming needed, and need to write one by one for the previous case.

Comment: I managed it but the values came in inverted keys but I remembered how to change it and managed to do it. Once again, thank you very much. Another thing, is there anything else I can do to evaluate you and help you with badges? You helped me a lot!

Comment: Thnak you so much too @MateusCostaLuz